# Improper foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have a database that maintains records of students, but it is failing in below case:
    1. If there does not exist a "Section" for a particular "Class", then there should not exist any student for the combination of that "Class" and "Section".
e.g Say, i have only two Section "A" and "B" for a class "Second", then all the students of Class "Second" must belongs to either Section "A" or "B", or we can say their can not exist any student who belongs to Class "Second" and Section "C".

My database structure:
StudentInfo table holds the data of student and has Student name, Student Class, Student Section column in it.
ClassnSec is a table that maintains the relationship between Class and Section.

I have made "Student Class" as F.K which points to "Class" and "Student Section" points to "Section".

e.g Entry in ClassnSec

```
-------------------------------------
ClassID    |   SectionID

  1                A
  1                B
  2                A
-------------------------------------
```

Entry in Student Info

```
-------------------------------------
Name   |  ClassID   |  Section ID
Mark        1           A
Joe         2           A
Gaurav      1           B
-------------------------------------
```

Now try to insert below, it should not be inserted since there is no row/entry for '2' & 'B', i.e there does not exist any section B for class 2. So inserting student data must be illegal.

```
-------------------------------------
Jon        2           B
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I'm aware, MySQL supports multi-column constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassNSec (
  ClassID int not null,
  SectionID int not null,
  constraint PK_ClassNSec PRIMARY KEY (ClassID,SectionID)
);
CREATE TABLE StudentInfo (
  StudentData varchar(10) not null,
  ClassID int not null,
  SectionID int not null,
  constraint FK_StudentInfo_ClassNSec FOREIGN KEY (ClassID,SectionID)
    references ClassNSec (ClassID,SectionID)
);
```

Which prevents any mismatch of classes and sections. You might (now) want to consider whether you want/need the individual class and section foreign key constraints.

Comment: I did somethign similar to this. Now, i think it might break down when "1. ClassNSec has entry for ClassID=2, and SectionID='A',   and another entry for ClassID=1, SectionID='B'", and in StudentInfo when you try to input a student detail with "Class=2" and Section='B', sql should accept it since it StudentInfo.ClassID references to existing ClassNSec.ClassID as well as same for SectionID case.

Comment: @guptakvgaurav - I don't understand the example you're giving in the previous comment, and whether it's an example of something you want that isn't allowed by my answer, or something that my answer is allowing that you think should be prevented.

Comment: I think your answer is not a solution for my case that i have mentioned in Question. Because in your answer StudentInfo.ClassID refers to ClassNSec.ClassId and StudentInfo.SectionID refers to ClassNSec.SectionID, but i need to check that there must be SectionID value in ClassNSec where ClassNSec.ClassID = StudentInfo.StudentID. I will update my post and try to explain in better way

Comment: @guptakvgaurav - I'm looking at your update - and it's exactly the scenario that my answer addresses. Because it's a multi-column constraint, *both* column values have to match a row in the referenced table.

Comment: @guptakvgaurav - Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eae76) showing the insert you want to prevent being (rightly) rejected.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, i will cross check where i was making mistake. Thanks for answering